# Google Map location with Markers according to multiple postal codes with Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to show google map showing the pointers for locations of multiple postal codes?

I have multiple postal codes, I want to show those postal codes with pointers in the map together.

This is example how I want this to work (http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a13egtc0d)

Comment: Are you looking to display the area associated with each postal code as a shape on the map or do you just want to display a single marker for each postal code, located somewhere within the postal code area?

Comment: I want to display area pointing with marker on th same map for all postal codes.

Comment: I want to provide postal code and google map should search for it and show me map for all postal code in the same place together.

Comment: How are you planning on "providing the postal codes"?  The "best" solution is to geocode them offline and include the geographic coordinates.  You can geocode them on page load, but if there are more than ~10, you will have to handle the API rate limit (the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status response).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understood you have an array of postal codes like this.

```
var postalCodes = [
    '10405', // Berlin
    ...
];
```

You want to convert each of these ZIP codes to a marker on the map. For this purpose you can use Google's geocoding API. All you need to do is create a `GeoCoder` object and call its `geocode` function with the postal code and a country hint.

```
geocoder.geocode({
    address: postalCode,
    region: countryHint // e.g. 'DE' for Germany
}, function(result, status) {
    // Create marker
}
```

A working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6x8yge4/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var postalCodes = [
    '01067', // Dresden
    '10405', // Berlin
    '20359', // Hamburg
];

function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5167, 12.1833),
        zoom:   6
    });

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < postalCodes.length; ++i) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                address: postalCodes[i],
                region: 'DE'
            }, function(result, status) {
                if (status == 'OK' && result.length > 0) {
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: result[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[image: Map with markers]

Answer (score 0):

This is the reference to use API properly.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Here is the logic, you have to create multiple LatLng objects with latitudes and longitudes.

Create a map object.

Create multiple marker objects for those LatLag objects and then bind those markers to map object.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP is looking to convert postal codes to markers on the map. Your link just shows how to create a marker for known latitude and longitude.

Comment: Because i know logic and need to write code. If you have ready code please share with us.